# Having issues parsing json data to a type array in React NextJS

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-hooks

I am having the following issue. I want to make a fetch that gets json data. use a parser to parse that data to an array of a certain type that is given to the parser as an argument. Im very new to React and i would really appreciate some help. Thanks in advance!

This is page.tsx:

```
"use client";
import CollapsingTable from "@/components/admin-dashboard/CollapsingTable";
import PageHeading from "@/components/admin-dashboard/PageHeading";
import fetchData from "@/lib/services/fetchData";
import parseData from "@/lib/services/parseData";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export default function ProductPage() {
  const dataUrl = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users";
  const [userList, setUsers] = useState<User[]>([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const x = fetchData(dataUrl).then((json) => {
      const users: User[] | null = parseData<User>(json) || [];//this does not work
      console.log(users);
      console.log(typeof users[0]);
      setUsers(users);
      console.log(userList);
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <PageHeading
        title={"Product Management"}
        href={"products"}
        children={undefined}
      ></PageHeading>
      {/* <CollapsingTable data={data} /> */}
    </>
  );
}
```

This is fetchData.ts:

```
export default async function getAllObjects(url: string) {
  const response = await fetch(url);

  if (!response.ok) throw new Error("Fetching objects failed");
  return response.json();
}
```

This is parseData.ts:

```
export default function parseAllObjects<T>(jsonString: string): T[] | null {
  try {
    return JSON.parse(jsonString) as T[];
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error parsing JSON:", error);
    return null;
  }
}
```

And this is my type (in this case User):

```
type User = {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  username: string;
  email: string;
  address: {
    street: string;
    suite: string;
    city: string;
    zipcode: string;
    geo: {
      lat: string;
      lng: string;
    };
  };
  phone: string;
  website: string;
  company: {
    name: string;
    catchPhrase: string;
    bs: string;
  };
};
```

The error i currently get in the browser is as follows:

```
Error parsing JSON: SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'o', "[object Obj"... is not valid JSON
```

Comment: What about const users: User[] | null = parseData<User>(json[0]) || []; ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, needed to parse the json data using this instead of a type:

```
{data.map((person, index) => (...etc...))}
```

Answer (score 0):

In this line also add await, Like this:

`await const x = fetchData(dataUrl).then((json) => {`

And I think after this you have to change this `export default function ProductPage() {`  to `export default async function ProductPage() {`  (**async** is added due to await)

Thanks, try and let me know if this works!